# transform from /base_link to /map

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, amcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was following the navigation tutorials. I have a map already, now I'm starting map_server and amcl as described in the tutorials but I'm getting following message:

```
Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before 
running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between '/map' and
'/base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more 
unconnected trees.
```

The robot is being displayed in the corner of the map and setting pose estimation does not work (I get a message e.g. "`Setting pose: 4.996 2.068 -2.645 [frame=/map]`" but nothing happens).

tftree looks like this (I have a kinect mounted on a car-like robot):

[tf tree http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/2531/82783897.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/2531/82783897.png)

so obviously map -> odom are not connected. Is that the reason pose-estimation does not work? How/where should I connect them? For testing I've tried static_transform_publisher (map to odom) but it did not change anything.

I'll be grateful for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28171/transform-from-/base_link-to-/map/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fixed it. my mistakes were:

- scan_topic was not properly set in amcl
- both laser_scan_matcher and my node were publishing tf odom->base_link

after fixing that I can set pose estimation in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-20**:
Hi, I have similar kind of problems.
1.How and where you have set scan_topic in amcl? I can't locate it properly; can you please mention it explicitly.
2. I have similar structure with you in the upper half of the image except one more tf called /base_footprint representing the robot platform between /odom and /base_link (representing sensor mounting point.). What should be global_frame and robot_base_frame in local_costmap_params.yaml and global_costmap_params.yaml(I want to use static map for global cost map)?

Thank in advance @Cav

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual convention for these mobile robot frames is described in [REP-0105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html).

Localization would normally provide the `/map->/odom` transform.

Why did `static_transform_publisher` not work? What parameter did you pass it?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-02-22**:
So amcl should provide the transformation in my case? I've tried this:

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-22**:
Yes. That transform looks OK to me. I do it the same, except for specifying 1000 ms instead of 100 ms.